# Ubuntu touch desktop mode display settings

Tags: ubuntu-touch, fonts, display-resolution, dpi

I have a couple of questions about the desktop mode on ubuntu touch (I currently have a Meizu Pro 5).

When I connect the phone to an external display (1920x1080 screen, I think, using a Microsoft display adapter), the text is a bit small. Is there a way to increase the font size? I also have quite alot aliasing. Is there a way to decrease the screen resolution?

Comment: Parameters in gsettings in org.gnome.desktop.interface don't affect these font sizes.